# ASP.NET CORE - How to set allowDoubleEscaping value to true in Kestrel server?

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

How to set allowDoubleEscaping in Kestrel?

Do we have any option in  CreateDefaultBuilder() for that ?

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options./// ???
                })
         .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Getting the below error

> The request contained a double escape sequence and request filtering
> is configured on the Web server to deny double escape sequences.

Comment: Do you really need to do that? I don't think Kestrel rejects `+` the way IIS does

Comment: Unfortunately not, Kestrel doesn't know about the allowDoubleEscaping config from IIS.